# Should I care about main, restricted, multiverse universe?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm currently learning about dpkg and apt, and I can see that the repository of e.g. ubuntu is structured in the following manner:

Under the `dists` directory, we have a list of `dists-suites` such as `focal`, `focal-updates`, `focal-security` etc.

Under each of these, we have a hierarchy of `main`, `multiverse`, `restricted` and `universe`.
I read in the [docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) what this means basically.

My questions are:

1. Should I care whether I install from `main`, `universe`, `multiverse` etc.? In which usecases should I change the default settings in the sources.list file?
2. Same question for `updates`, `security`, `backports` etc.?
3. What are `backports` anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of this is addressed in [the detailed description of repositories in the Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories).

1. You should care if you care about different levels of support, and different licenses:

   | Component | Supported by | [Support duration](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Management_of_releases) | License |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | `main` | Canonical | Five years (LTS) | Free / open source |
   | `restricted` | Third-party provider | Five years (LTS) | Proprietary, source might not be available |
   | `universe` | Third-party (typically, Debian) | No commitment | Free / open source |
   | `multiverse` | Third-party | No commitment | Non-free, patent-encumbered etc. |
2. `security` provides security fixes. `updates` additionally provides fixes for serious bugs. `backports` provides new versions of (some) packages.
3. Most of the time, new versions of packages are only made available in subsequent releases of Ubuntu. Sometimes however it can be useful to make a new version available to users of older releases, even though it isn’t a candidate for `updates`; this is where `backports` comes in. Note that `backports` isn’t tested as a whole, so in general you should only pull in specific packages you’re interested in from that repository.